# Why are these boolean expressions in this if/else statement not evaluating as expected?

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean-logic

Could you please take a short look and tell me what's wrong with the code?

```
e = eval(input('enter 1 '))
f = eval(input('enter 3 '))

if e != 1 and f != 3:
    print('you got it wrong!')
else:
    print("correct")
```

So the problem here is if I enter 1 of 2 numbers correct, it says that it is correct but it shouldn't because I have an "and" operator ?

Of course I could change the code to something like this which would work fine:

```
if e == 1 and f == 3:
    print('correct')
else:
    print("you got it wrong!")
```

But on the other side I would like to understand what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks :)

Comment: `e != 1` means "e is wrong".  `f != 3` means "f is wrong".  Your `if` statement's condition is "e is wrong AND f is wrong".

Comment: https://brilliant.org/wiki/de-morgans-laws/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if e != 1 and f != 3:` means if `e` is wrong **and** `f` is also wrong. But as you mentioned, you entered one right, then the `and` statement doesn't get through, since one of them are still right.

You need `or`:

```
if e != 1 or f != 3:
    print('you got it wrong!')
else:
    print("correct")
```

Btw, I recommend you to use `int` instead of `eval` (since `eval` is bad practice, and you are converting to an integer):

```
e = int(input('enter 1 '))
f = int(input('enter 3 '))
```

Read: [Why is using 'eval' a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)

Answer (score 1):

The logic is wrong. Use [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Engineering):

`x AND y` invert → `x NAND y` → `NOT x OR NOT y`

where `x` stands for `e == 1` and `y` stands for `f == 3`